# Unique timestamp column for every record in the dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe which needs to have a unique load timestamp column. no two records in the dataframe should have same value in this field.

I tried using inbuilt methods such CURRENT_TIMESTAMP etc but doesn't work. I even tried creating a udf to generate the timestamp as below

```scala
val generateUniqueTimestamp = udf(() => new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS").format(new java.util.Date()).toString)

var df = dataFrame.withColumn("LOAD_TS", generateUniqueTimestamp())
```

Lets say, three records in data frame, it should have an extra field with a timestamp

Actual result

```
rec1 ,2019-09-05 22:00:00:000  
rec2 ,2019-09-05 22:00:00:000  
rec3 ,2019-09-05 22:00:00:000
```

Expected result

```
rec1 ,2019-09-05 22:00:00:000  
rec2 ,2019-09-05 22:00:00:001  
rec3 ,2019-09-05 22:00:00:002
```

Comment: Use monotonically_increasing_id and add it to a base epoch then try converting it to time stamp

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , Yeah that can be done but wanted something which would avoid using a sequence or random number solution.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps solved the issue for now, Might be a bad way to do it though.

Created a method and registered it with spark udf using.

```
 spark.udf.register("uniquetimestamp", uniquetimestap(_: String))
```

Created an empty column using

```
.withColumn("LOAD_TS", lit(null: String))
```

Extracted all columns in dataframe and then iterated through them to generate SqlExpr. (all column goes in as it is expect for LOAD_TS

```
//(cast(uniquetimestamp(load_ts) as timestamp) as load_ts)

val df  =dataframe.selectExpr(sqlCastingExpr.split(","): _*)
```